# Fixing A Google Sheets Script So It Does Not Remove A Cell Formula When It Runs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script running nicely on Google Sheets:

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("K16:L16");
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
}
```

But, I have this effect here http://screencast.com/t/BOXzC0UZxFZ (short 1 min video show you the issue). Summary of the issue is that when the script runs in forces K16 to just show the current value of the formula and strips out the =sum formula I have in K16.

What do you think I need to do so that when the script runs, it will not automatically strip the K16 formula so K16 will continue updating to new values?

:)

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modification?

#### Modification point :

- In order to retrieve formulas in the cells, it uses `getFormulas()`.
- Insert the retrieved formulas.

#### Modified script :

In the most cases, the following modified script can be used. I think that in your case, the following modified script can be used.

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("K16:L16");
  var formula = range.getFormulas()[0]; // Added
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([[formula[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]); // Modified
}
```

There are sometimes the case that it requires to insert the formula using `setFormula()` as follows.

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("K16:L16");
  var formula = range.getFormulas()[0]; // Added
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  sheet.getRange("K16").setFormula(formula[0]); // Added
  sheet.getRange("L16").setValue(Math.max(values[0], values[1])); // Added
}
```

#### Reference :

- [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)
- [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.